# How to reset the Openbox configuration?

Tags: configuration, xubuntu, openbox

my Openbox does not work any longer. I'm using XFCE4 and the configuration Dialog for window-Decoration is blank and I only have one workspace. I haven't found any standard config in /etc/skel and no dirs in in my home named openbox but /.local/share/openbox/sessions. `$ openbox --replace --debug` didn't help me. How do I reset the configuration?

**UPDATE**

I have copied `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` to `~/.config/openbox`, but nothing has changed. The preferences dialog is empty and even if the file contains

```
<desktops>
  <!-- this stuff is only used at startup, pagers allow you to change them
       during a session

these are default values to use when other ones are not already set
       by other applications, or saved in your session

       use obconf if you want to change these without having to log out
       and back in -->
  <number>4</number>
  <firstdesk>1</firstdesk>
  <names>
    <!-- set names up here if you want to, like this:
    <name>desktop 1</name>
    <name>desktop 2</name>
    -->
    <name>desktop 1</name>
    <name>desktop 2</name>
    <name>desktop 3</name>
    <name>desktop 4</name>
  </names>
  <popupTime>875</popupTime>
  <!-- The number of milliseconds to show the popup for when switching
       desktops.  Set this to 0 to disable the popup. -->
</desktops>
```

I only have one Desktop. So, it seems openbox does not read the configuration file at all.

**UPDATE 2**
And http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp claims that rc.xml is valid xml.

**UPDATE 3**
Plainly running `obconf` brings back my desktops. I don't get why, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the user configuration files for openbox are located at

```
~/.config/openbox/
```

so removing that directory would restore default configuration.

This should work if you have not manually changed system configuration of openbox in `/etc`.

Comment: I had changed configuration in etc to change keymapping. that did not work but my taskbar is missing now. what to do?